# Argument passing for `newenvironment` wrapper of `tabularx`

Tags: environments, tabularx

I am trying to build a wrapper of the `tabularx` environment that adjusts the row spacing using `\newenvironment`. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{tabularxe}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}
}{
    \end{tabularx}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
}


\begin{document}
    
% intended code
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}r|X}
test & text\\
test & text
\end{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

% erroneous code
\begin{tabularxe}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}r|X}
test & text\\
test & text
\end{tabularxe}

\end{document}
```

But this code throws an error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. ...larx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}r|X}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: The manual of `tabularx` says you must use `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` instead of `\begin{tabularx}` and `\end{tabularx}` when defining environments based on it. You don't need to reset `\arraystretch`, because the scope of the redefinition ends as soon as `\end{tabularxe}` is found.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I will select your answer if you write it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tabularx` needs to absorb the entire content of the environment, a special technique is necessary in order to define environments based on it, namely to use `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx`, not `\begin{tabularx}` and `\end{tabularx}`.

Note that resetting `\arraystretch` is not needed, because the effect of `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` will end together with `\end{tabularxe}`.

Also setting `\hsize` in the `r` column does nothing at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % to better show the effect

\newenvironment{tabularxe}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \tabularx{#1}{#2}%
}{%
    \endtabularx
}


\begin{document}

\noindent    
\begin{tabularxe}{\textwidth}{r|X}
text & \lipsum[1][2-5]\\
text & \lipsum[2][2-5]
\end{tabularxe}

\bigskip

\noindent    
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r|X}
text & \lipsum[1][2-5]\\
text & \lipsum[2][2-5]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference is tiny, but noticeable.